# Need to have Excel autopopulate with conditional formatting for second sheet from series of positive tests

Tags: excel

I have created an Excel sheet that has a large series of tests on sheet one that has the name of the tests and a cell where comments will be written about the findings.  I need the sheet that has the test to have the an affiliated cell with the test cell and the comment cell populate to sheet two so that I can quickly copy and paste the summarized data into a specialized marketing handout.

I'm struggling with finding the correct formula to allow this to happen.  I have tried =IF variations with limited success that seemed to carry over everything rather than just the specific cells with the positive tests.

I'd appreciate any guidance on what formula should be written so this goal can be successful.

Comment: Some sample data and the expected output would be helpful here.

Comment: For "what formula should be written ..." need some sample data. For "name of the tests and a cell where comments will be written .. " need a clearer picture of where this info/cell/desired/output is located.

Comment: Thanks for the comments on clarity:

Comment: Thanks for the comments on clarity:  For the sample data, there are 3 vertical rows. From left to right, the first vertical row is blank and it's the row in which any positive statement will be made next to it, indicating it needs to be carried over to the second sheet.  The second vertical row is a list of the names of the test which go unaltered during testing but if a positive finding is indicated in the first row, this row is part of what needs to be carried over to the next sheet.  The third vertical row will be left for comments to be carried over to the second sheet as well if positive.

Comment: I'd like for something simple in the first row to be placed (i.e. an "X' or a "1") so that it's easy for the corresponding horizontal row test and comment to be carried over to the second sheet